# Google Maps Scalable Overlay

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i use this Snippet for a custom maps overlay:

http://jsfiddle.net/4cWCW/3/

I think this is the part were to Change it:

```
DebugOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};
```

I need to preserve the aspect ratio of the image while scaling.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. get the original height and width of the image
2. scale the new height to be the appropriate ratio of the new width (or vice versa, which ever you feel gives the best user experience).

```
  var origHeight = this.img.naturalHeight;
  var origWidth = this.img.naturalWidth;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (ne.x - sw.x) * origWidth/origWidth + 'px';
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cWCW/1078/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var overlay;

DebugOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.743388, -74.007592)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(40.73660837340877, -74.01852328);
  var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(40.75214181, -73.99661518216243);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);

  var srcImage = 'http://robincwillis.com/top/splash/04.jpg';

  overlay = new DebugOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);

  var markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: swBound,
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });

  var markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: neBound,
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerA, 'drag', function() {

    var newPointA = markerA.getPosition();
    var newPointB = markerB.getPosition();
    var newBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(newPointA, newPointB);
    overlay.updateBounds(newBounds);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerB, 'drag', function() {

    var newPointA = markerA.getPosition();
    var newPointB = markerB.getPosition();
    var newBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(newPointA, newPointB);
    overlay.updateBounds(newBounds);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerA, 'dragend', function() {

    var newPointA = markerA.getPosition();
    var newPointB = markerB.getPosition();
    console.log("point1" + newPointA);
    console.log("point2" + newPointB);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerB, 'dragend', function() {
    var newPointA = markerA.getPosition();
    var newPointB = markerB.getPosition();
    console.log("point1" + newPointA);
    console.log("point2" + newPointB);
  });

}

function DebugOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;
  this.div_ = null;
  this.setMap(map);
}

DebugOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.opacity = '0.5';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(img);
  this.img = img;
  that = this;
  this.img.onload = function() {
    console.log("onload: img width=" + this.width + ' height=' + this.height);
    that.draw();
  }
  this.div_ = div;
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};

DebugOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());
  var div = this.div_;
  var origHeight = this.img.naturalHeight;
  var origWidth = this.img.naturalWidth;
  console.log("oH=" + origHeight + " oW=" + origWidth + " ratio=" + origWidth / origWidth);
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = ((ne.x - sw.x) * (origWidth / origWidth)) + 'px';
  console.log("width=" + div.style.width + " height=" + div.style.height);
  // div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};


DebugOverlay.prototype.updateBounds = function(bounds) {
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.draw();
};

DebugOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
};

initialize();
//google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah nice but now the sw marker doesn't stay at the sw corner if scaling. Do you have a solution for that? And the greatest would be if i can drag the overlay additional.